# Proving $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$ using Abel's Theorem / Deriving Pythagoras Theorem from Abel's Theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, homogeneous-equation, wronskian

I've been trying to prove the following,

*$\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$ from Abel's theorem, and from the fact that $y_1 = \cos(x)$ and $y_2 = \sin(x)$ form a set of fundamental solutions for the standard harmonic equation $y'' + y = 0$, that satisfy the initial conditions at x = 0; $y_1(0)=1, y'_1(0)=0, y_2(0)=0, y'_2(0)=1$*

*(hint: furthermore you may use the definition of the Wronskian, of course)*
which kinda confused me, to be honest, but I've decided to use it. Using the definition of the Wronskian I've found

$W = c \cdot exp \left( -\int p(x)dx \right) = ce^{-x}$

$ce^{-x} = y_1y'_2 - y_2y'_1 = -sin^2(x) - cos^2(x)$

Then by using $y_1(0)=1$ and $y_2(0)=0$ we can find $c=1$ therefore $W = -e^{-t}$

Now I know that by simply deriving $sin^2(x)+cos^2(x)=1$ we find $0=0$, which proves it. However, I cannot find a way to prove it with Abel's Theorem, which states:

--

if $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solutions of the second order lineaer differential equation
$L[y] = y''+p(t)y'+q(t)y=0$

where p and q are continuous on an open interval I, then the Wronskian $W[y_1,y_2](t)$ is given by

$W[y_1, y_2](t) = c \cdot \exp\left(\int p(t)dt\right)$

where c is a certain constant that depends on $y_1$ and $y_2$, but not on $t$. Further, $W[y_1, y_2](t)$ either is zero for all t in I or else is never zero in I

--

Now I'm pretty much stuck on what to do, so any help is appreciated

Comment: I don't agree with your evaluation of $W(x)$, Isn't $p(t)=0$ for all $t$?

Comment: Oef yeah, that's a silly mistake. However, then $W = ce^{-1}$ and this would not make the equation any better, I think, since it becomes $-ce^{-1} = sin^2(x) + cos^2(x) = 1$, right?

Comment: Oh wait, I think I get it. Now the C changes ($c = -e^1$ ), which makes the equation

$-e^{-1} \cdot -e^1 = e^0 = 1=sin^2(x)+cos^2(x)$

Would that be correct?

Comment: A comment: you are using $x$ and $t$ as your variables. These should probably be all $x$ or all $t$.

Comment: Further, if $p \equiv 0$, then $W[y_1, y_2] = c$, $e$ does not appear since you have $e^0$. So you have from the definition of the Wronskian $c = \sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x)$. Your initial conditions then give you what the value of $c$ is.